# c# abstract inheritance design question

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract

I am somewhat new to C# and am trying to do a good job following OO principles and write good code. After spending a couple of hours searching for my question, I found some vague answers, but nothing solid enough for me feel confident about. There is a good chance I am asking a dumb question and approaching this problem from the wrong angle.

My Question is: Say I wanted to create a abstract base card class, from which I could compose any card game (for example lets compare a basic deck of playing cards and Magic:The Gathering). Following this: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-type-code-with-class, I was able to create a PokerCardType, which is basically a glorified enum for each card in the standard deck. My problem arises from how to create an abstract Card class that requires an instance of a CardType in it, but the specific instance is not determined. My first thought was to create an abstract CardType class, which would have some way of requiring a set of static CardType objects for whatever the subclass would be, but I cannot figure out how to do that. My other question is, does this idea really even make sense, or should I just make two separate class structures, one for poker and one for Magic. If you are wondering why I would want to do this, it is really just for my own education. Thanks for the help or any links you can provide.

Comment: I would first ask what common set of "things"/attributes do Magic Cards have with Poker Cards?

Comment: All of your answers basically point to the same idea, are there enough things in common between Magic and Poker to create some base object, probably not. Before I started reading more and more into it, I thought the best way to go would be simply keeping them separate, but quickly was consumed in the world of inheritance. As suggested by many, I am going to keep them separate. Thanks for all of the quick responses. Any one of them could have been considered the correct answer, but I am giving it to taylonr because he showed how you could actually do it if it made sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of an abstract class Deck, with specific implementations of PokerDeck and MagicDeck.  As others have said, I'm not sure it's the best example, because there really isn't a lot of commonality between the games.

Maybe if you did something like Hand with SpadesHand, HeartsHand, PinochleHand, PresidentsHand where you would have various #s of cards in each hand.  Each game has a method of "PlayNextCard" and they have different rules, but all revolve around putting a card from your hand on a common pile.

```
public abstract class Deck
    {
          public int NumberOfCards{get; private set;}

          public IEnumerable<Card> Cards {get; private set;}

          public void Shuffle()
          {
              Cards = RandomizeCards();
          }

          protected abstract IEnumerable<Card> CreateCardList();

    }

    public class PokerDeck
    {
         public PokerDeck()
         {
              NumberOfCards = 52;
              Cards = CreateCardList();
         }
    }

    public class MagicDeck
    {
         public MagicDeck()
         {
             NumberOfCards = 10000; // have no idea
              Cards = CreateCardList();
         }
    }
```

Then you implement the CreateCardList on each concrete class.  So the poker has 2-A for Hearts, Spades, Clubs and Diamonds.  Magic has whatever a magic deck has.

You don't have to implement the Shuffle method because it's performed in the base class.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the wrong path in my opinion. Following OO principles and writing good code has quite some overlapping, but is no way the same. Don't try to follow OO principles, because somebody told you so. Follow them, because they fit your need to solve a real problem. The usual Shape->Circle/Rectangle/...->Draw example is just nonsens and is confusing people.

It's hard to summarize, but I'll try: To implement some abstract class, you need a good abstraction. Something like "Card" is not the abstraction. The abstraction would be the operations you can do with a card. Those operations obviously depend on the context, so in different context (programms) you might differnt good abstractions for a "card".

If it's for your education: Implement a poker game without any fancy OO stuff. Then implement Magic without any fancy OO stuff. Look what they have in common. Try to remove as much duplication as possible. Now you will find some OO principles to very helpful. And the abstraction of a card will evolve automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You're way overdoing abstraction here. Unless you're designing an extremely general card game engine (and I mean extremely), I can't see any reason why it should be the case that a deck of poker cards and a deck of Magic cards can be thought of as "is a `Deck`" for some abstract class `Deck`.

Just start with the simplest thing that works.

```
class PokerDeck { }
class MagicDeck { }
```

If later you find that they have enough in common to extract an abstract base class `Deck`, do it then. My point is that it's highly unlikely you'll find this to be the case. You could certainly try, but it's a likely just a huge exercise in mental masturbation with very little gain.

Note: inheritance is easily the most misunderstood and misused OOP concept.

Comment: Deck is  a bad example because there is shared functionality.

Comment: Yea, years later I still cannot understand when, and how to properly use inheritance :(

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have a static CardType class, which can be defined with the set of Card instances that you want to support.  If that's not dynamic enough for you, it can still be a static class which knows about all of the Card Types that have been registered with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd break the requirements down even further.  What is it about cards from poker and magic that you want to represent with a base class?  Aside from having a height and width dimension, they share very little in common as far as how they are used in their respective games.  Poker cards can't be tapped.  Magic cards can't be used to assemble a flush.  The cards themselves don't do much.

They're shuffle-able, I suppose...  If you wanted to model that, you could just create an IShuffleable interface that both classes could implement.

To directly answer what I think you're asking, you can probably solve it with generics.  Say you want to have a deck of cards:

```
public class CardDeck<T> : where T:BaseCardType
{
   private List<T> _cards new List<T>();

   public void Shuffle()
   {
      // blah blah
   }

   public void SomethingElseYouCanDoWithADeck
   { }
}
```

I just don't thinkt hat's going to do very much for you...  Can you elaborate on how you would use these classes, once designed?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of abstract classes and inheritance is to classes that are close to the same thing. Normally it's when a subclass is a "better defined" or "more specific" instance than just the basic type.

For example: A police car is a more specific version of a sedan so a police car would inherit from a sedan. But a MTG card is not a more specific instance of a poker card, nor vice versa. You may be able to do this for some card games, such as poker cards and Uno cards, because they share common traits like face value and suit/color.